# How to generate flat type model name on view

Tags: asp.net-core

I've got a problem where i have a view with complex model and from that view i'm trying to sent form to the another action with simple model that incorporated in complex one. How i can avoid adding [ComplexModel].[PlainModel] prefixed from the [ComplexModel].[PlainModel].[Id]  generated by default. I want just to have name of [Id]

The structure of classes (not real but tak it just for tests):

```
class A
{
    public B PlainClass { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public int Id { get; }
}
```

So instead of having the name PlainClass.Id

```
<input asp-for="PlainClass.Id">
```

I'd like to send with form only [Id] name

```
<input asp-for="Id">
```

Comment: The model you use for your view should be same model you post. Anything else is going to be problematic.

Comment: But, in case you want to still do that, I think you can simply override the name by setting the name attribute directly. So, something like `<input name="Id" asp-for="Id" />`.